# Assigning each word in a string the score attributed to that string

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im stuck on this part of a problem. I need to read in a text file of about 8k reviews but they are formatted for easy processing. The number in front of the sentence for example

3 this movie was enjoyable and well written .

each word in that sentence should have a score of 3 and be put into a hash table with the word, score, and number of occurrences.

```
def main():
    fin = open("movieReviews.txt")
    # read lines from file one at a time
    count = 0
    for line in fin:
       # tokenize each review
        reviewToken = line.split()

        if reviewToken[0].isdigit():
            count = count + 1    

    print(count)
```

im just stuck on how to assign each word in a sentence the value at the beginning of it with sentences being different lengths.

Comment: What do you mean by "each word in that sentence should have a score of 3" ?

Comment: in the example i gave, the value 3, which is in the beginning of the sentence is then assigned as a score to each word in that particular sentence. I should add, i have to implement this into a hashtable after i get this part figured out

Comment: What if your file has one line: `3 this movie is good` and another `7 silly movie`. What score does `movie` have?

Comment: well in this case reviews are 0 - 4 but in ur example. movie would update its score to 10 and its number of occurrences to 2

Comment: So a word's score is the sum of the line scores for all of the lines in which the word appears.

Comment: Correct, this is processed through about 8500 reviews

Answer (score 1):

I'd split it into two dictionaries, one for scores and one keeping count

```
with open(filename) as f:
    counts = {}
    scores = {}
    for line in f:
        i, *line = line.split()
        for word in line:
            if word not in counts:
                counts[word] = 0
            if word not in scores:
                scores[word] = 0
            count[word] += 1
            scores[word] += int(i)
```

You could make this a little more compact by making `scores` and `counts` into `defaultdict`s from the `collections` module.